# Ubuntu 18.04 HDMI not working

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I just upgraded from one LTS to another, (only format /boot partition). HDMI connection hangs on a black screen and blinking pointer, TV starts auto search for source input.
I'm running on Intel integrated graphics, Lenovo Ideapad Y530.
Updated.
/etc/X11/Xorg.conf doesn't exist, can't find how to create one.

**lspci | grep VGA**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

**xrandr** (Connected HDMI, turn on TV, can't see anything, just write down command and wait for it to happen to press enter).

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   1280x800      60.01*+  59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
SVIDEO-1 unknown connection (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   848x480       59.94 +
   640x480       59.94 +
   1024x768      59.94  
   800x600       59.94
```

Please help!

Comment: I also tried this:

    xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080
    xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP-1
xrandr: cannot find output "eDP-1"

Got the last line as result.

Comment: Please click on the edit link above at left, and add your additional results from xrandr to the original post, so the original post is complete with all your findings.